# After Load More is clicked once i get the issue waiting for element to no longer be visible:

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I have a Search Screen where after I enter the search criteria and search, a Load More button will display if there are more than 30 records. The problem here is it clicks the Load More button for the first time but is not clicking a second or third time.

The scenario is I need to click until the Load More button becomes disabled.

Below is my code any inputs

```java
   List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody[@role='rowgroup']/tr"));
            int rowcount = rows.size();

            String loadmoreXpath = AppXPathsConstants.buttonXpath_replace.replace("XXXX","Load More");
        
            if(driver.findElements(By.xpath(loadmoreXpath)).size()!= 0) 
            {
                
            WebElement loadmoreElem = DriverUtil.getFluentWaitElementByXPath(loadmoreXpath,20, driver);
        
            do
            {
                
                WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,60);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'mat-button-wrapper') and contains(normalize-space(),'Load More')]")));
                loadmoreElem.click();
                DriverUtil.waitTime(6000);
                WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
                 w.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(loadmoreXpath)));
            }

            while(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'mat-button-wrapper') and contains(normalize-space(),'Load More')]")).size()>0);
            }

And on running the code i get the below issue:
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to no longer be visible: By.xpath: //span[contains(@class,'mat-button-wrapper') and contains(normalize-space(),'Load More')] (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

Comment: Are you receiving any errors when you try to click the button the second time?

Comment: it is not clicking on the Load more button the second time and there are no errors it just clicks the first time - @Kate Paulk - any inputs

Answer (score 1):

With what you are attempting to do, you should be using a loop structure.

I'd recommend something like this (no guarantees on the code - I haven't worked with Java in over 20 years):

```
WebElement loadmore = getFluentWaitElementByXPath(loadmoreXpath, 20, driver);

// assuming "loadmore" is the button to click
// also we need to wait until the extra results are loaded

while (loadmore.isDisplayed() && loadmore.isClickable())
{
   loadmore.click();
   // do the wait again
   // once the wait is done, search for the button again - this ensures you won't have a stale element exception to worry about
   loadmore = driver.getElement(by.xpath(loadmoreXPath));
   
}
```

You could also use a loop that checks `while (!loadmore.isDisabled())`. The key thing is that you have a means of checking that the extra set of search results is loaded and relocating the load more button.

You may also need to consider scrolling to the button, since the list may get lengthy.

Comment: i get what you are saying but just wanted to know if there are more than 10 load more button  i need to keep giving this line  // once the wait is done, search for the button again - this ensures you won't have a stale element exception to worry about
   loadmore = driver.getElement(by.xpath(loadmoreXPath)); -@Kate Paulk

Comment: have made changes like this - do
     {
     PageUtil.scrolltoBottom(driver);
     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,120);
              wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'mat-button-wrapper') and contains(normalize-space(),'Load More')]")));
     loadmoreElems.click();
     DriverUtil.waitTime(5000);
              if(!loadmoreElem.isDisplayed())
              {
     
     break;

    } }
              while(loadmoreElem.isDisplayed());

Comment: but leads to stale elemnt exception in the line if(!loadmoreElem.isDisplayed())

Comment: @jaym There is no loop in your logic , so the execution happens only once . You should use some form of loop . But make sure you rediscover the element as the DOM changes after click and this results in stale element error.

Comment: updated my code with changes - it does lead to stale element exception and have added the wait.until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(loadmoreElems)); but now getting :  org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element ([[ChromeDriver: chrome on WINDOWS (fb2814833df250e07c6cf007f92d758e)] -> xpath: //span[contains(@class,'mat-button-wrapper') and contains(normalize-space(),'Load More')]]) to become stale (tried for 10 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval) -@PDHide

Comment: if i remove that line it leads to stale element - any inputs  - @PDHide and if i rediscover the element once again how do i modify the code

Comment: Added the element again that needs to be clicked but the stale element exception comes on adding any leads on this - @PDHide

Comment: @jaym - please update your question with your updated code and the results you are getting. It's difficult to evaluate code in comments.

Comment: @Kate Paulk - have added the updated Code with stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I think its because, you are defining `loadmoreElems` (within the loop) after you perform the click operation. So it click on the `Load More` button one time because you have defined `loadmoreElems` outside the loop. After the 1st click you are not defining it before click operation and the previously defined `loadmoreElems` is no longer valid.

Define it before that and try:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class,'mat-button-wrapper') and contains(normalize-space(),'Load More')]")));
loadmoreElems = DriverUtil.getFluentWaitElementByXPath(loadmoreXpath,20, driver);
loadmoreElems.click();
if(!loadmoreElem.isDisplayed())...
```